# Android unit test only compiles if placed in androidTest folder

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I am using Android Studio 1.1.0. I am trying to separate my unit tests and integration tests. The integration tests are in folder `src/androidTest/java`. I am trying to create my unit tests in `src/test/java/`. This should be possible as per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html).

> Android Plug-in for Gradle version 1.1.0 and higher allows you to
>   create a source directory (src/test/java) in your project to store
>   JUnit tests that you want to run on a local machine.

My `build.gradle` dependencies look somewhat like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.+'
    }
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile files('libs/dexmaker-mockito-1.0.jar')
    androidTestCompile files('libs/dexmaker-1.0.jar')

    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
}
```

This should work by all accounts but a sample test I wrote does not compile at all if I place it in `src/test/java`. It compiles and runs fine if I place it in `src/androidTest/java`. What am I missing? I cannot upgrade to Android Studio 1.2 at the moment. I have set my `Test Artifact` to `Unit Test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using unit test then add your dependencies as `testCompile ...`

And you need to change your build variant.

Check http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support